# Is it possible to get the retain count of a Closure in Swift?

Tags: swift, closures, automatic-ref-counting, retaincount

In Swift, Closures are reference types. Which means (I think, please correct me if I'm wrong) that they have a lifetime managed by a retain count. I can get the retain count of an object using [CFGetRetainCount](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corefoundation/1521288-cfgetretaincount), but this doesn't work for Closures because they can't conform to [AnyObject](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/anyobject) (or any protocol for that matter).

Before anyone jumps in and tells me I'm doing the wrong thing by trying to get the retain count of anything manually, I know. It's purely for experimentation to prove to myself that this is how Closure lifetime is managed by the runtime.

Comment: You can try using Memory Debug Graph in Xcode which provides visual interpretation of any object's retain count at any point of time

Comment: The source for the swift compiler and runtime are available.  I'd suggest reading that.  Or modifying it to print() some diagnostics.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CFGetRetainCount` if you declare the closure as `@convention(block)`, as this will instruct the compiler to generate an Objective-C block, which is for all intended purposes an object:

```swift
let closure: @convention(block) () -> Void = {
    print("test")
}

print(CFGetRetainCount(unsafeBitCast(closure, to: CFTypeRef.self)))
```